# since/from the first grunt of

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning, idioms

The *first grunt* of what in both quotes below, or why *first grunt*?

> We all love to be told a story; it is the oldest form of communication. People have loved to be told a story **since the first grunt**.

Source: On Writing Well

> Good grief, its only an idiom. Don't waste another precious moment of
>   worry on such nonsense. All language, from the very **first grunt and
>   groan**, has been bastardized to suit the user. You Uprights, superior
>   you say.

Source: A user comment on [TheFreeDictionary](http://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postst6532_i-could-care-less.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It is a reference to the beginnings of humankind. Early humans probably couldn't communicate using words and complicated grammar. They probably used hand gestures, like pointing, and **grunts** to communicate. Here's an [animation](https://youtu.be/8fWYEttovtM?t=112).

There was definitely a **first** grunt, but to say that these things started from the **first** one is an exaggeration. *Since the first grunt* is another way of saying "since the beginning",  "since the beginning of mankind", or something like "since the first time mankind began to speak".